# openCV VideoCapture is several frames behind

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am making a program that uses a webcam to track objects in real time.  The resulting display is always a few frames behind.  For an example, when I move the camera to point at a new spot, it still shows the first position for a few frames.

Here is my program, it should find the circles in the frame and return an image with them circled:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles() # parameters removed
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        #draw circle
        cv2.circle() # parameters removed

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As you can see it takes some time to process each frame.  I expected the it to be choppy, but the result shows images from several seconds ago.

Comment: It shouldn't be that slow, but drawing functions are quite time consuming. Try drawing at most, say, 3 circles and see what happens.

Comment: If you're PC is old/a bit slow then that might also have an effect. But I also agree with Miki

Comment: @Miki I am running it on my raspberry pi.  The drawing speed and or processing speed is not the problem.  When I move the camera, it takes about 5 frames for it to catch up.  What I think its doing is returning from a query instead of returning the current state.

Comment: That seems something caused by the pi... Probably you have better luck on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Miki Is there a way to use the webcam more like a camera, or change the query size?